# Azure Portal & QNA chatbot template

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-bot-service

i tried to create a bot from QNA template in Azure portal and the dropdown menu only give

me the choice to create new QNA one instead using existing one. I'm logged on QNAmaker and Azure portal with the same ms account but nothing works. The option "create existing QNA" does not create it in my QNAMaker services pages !!!

Just to say that I'm in trial mode in Azure ...

If you have any ideas !

Regards

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new chatbot from the Azure QNA template and then you'll be able to use your existing QnA be simply changing in the appsettings the key to the existing one.

Comment: Thanks a lot but from where to where I change the key ?

Comment: When you click Publish on the qnamaker.ai page you will get a sample request with your Subscription key and other info. You can use that in the Azure AppSettings section from your bot.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll give it a try ! Regards.

Answer (score -2):

First you need to register a qna service from Azure portal and then with the same account login into qnamaker.io there you go to step 2 and fill the detail.
now you can choose your knowledgebase name and can populate your knowledgebase for QnA.
Then you need to publish it, there you will get details like knowledgebase id, auth key and host url. These will be used in code.
For step by step guide you can visit this [link](https://sdharshraj.github.io/2018/05/20/migrating-to-or-creating-new-qnamaker-with-microsoft-bot-framework.html).